# Why is NSFileManager not working?

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

I've written some code to copy a file (dbtemplate.sqlite) from the application package to the library. However, no file shows up in the library and every time I start the application it logs the text that it copied the template. There are no errors showing up in the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"~/Library/AppSafe/database/db.sqlite"]) {

    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:@"~/Library/AppSafe/database" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:@"dbtemplate.sqlite" toPath:@"~/Library/AppSafe/database/db.sqlite" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"copied template");

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you have to pass a full path into the `NSFileManager` methods, and using a tilde-prefixed path won't work.

So instead of using `@"~/Library/..."`, use:

```
[@"~/Library/..." stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
```

Comment: Or, more reliably, ask the NSFileManager for a path to the relevant folder in Application Support. Hard-coding a path may/will (some paths will, some paths may) break after you turn on sandboxing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies in `copyItemAtPath:`, since the string you give is not a proper path. Use something like `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResourceWithName:]` to get the actual path to the resource. Also, I'm not sure that the ~ in your paths is supported - you may need to use some function of NSString to expand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving files in the documents folder, im not sure if you can even save files in the library folder. Use this code to create a path to your file in the documents folder:

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
```

And simply check if it exists like this:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
```

So better move your files to the documents folder.

Comment: It is possible to save files in certain places within Library; whether any of them would be more appropriate than Documents would depend on the file's purpose. (Documents is only for things created by the user.) Either way, stapling paths together is a deprecated approach. The correct solution is to ask the NSFileManager object for a path within the desired directory; when running sandboxed under Mac OS X, NSFileManager will unlock your access to that file, whereas a handmade path won't.